# What is the order of processed rewrite rules of cq dispatcher?

Tags: aem

I'm going to apply the following rewrite rules on my dispatcher

```
RewriteRule ^content/feeds/networkapp/ios/1.0/config(.*)?$    /content/feeds/ios/feed.config.json [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^content/feeds/networkapp/ios/((\d\.)+\d/)?config(.*)?$    /content/feeds/ios/$1feed.config.json [L,NC]
```

Does first rewtite rule will be executed?

I need to revrite :

1. `...../ios/1.0/config` to `/ios/feed.config.json`
2. `...../ios/x.x.x/config` to `/ios/x.x.x/feed.config.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may see,I have used `[L]` flag. This means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.

```
RewriteRule ^content/feeds/networkapp/ios/1.0/config(.*)?$    /content/feeds/betnow/ios/feed.config.json [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^content/feeds/networkapp/ios/((\d\.)+\d/)?config(.*)?$    /content/feeds/ios/$1feed.config.json [L,NC]
```

[[L] flag on apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)